# Opposite of e.prevent default?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a javascript extension for chrome. It will allow you to edit the page like a word document. Here's the code:

```
document.body.contentEditable = 'true';
document.designMode='on';
void 0;
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
};
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
document.body.contentEditable = 'false';
document.designMode='off';
void 0;
}
});
```

The problem is, whenever I'm done and press esc (hence the `if (keycode == 27)`), sometimes the links don't work. I think that what happens is that `e.preventDefault` is still going. Can I have a little help?

Comment: I think you're not removing the event listener. Try to look at addEventListener and its friend removeEventListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you really need the [void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

There's no thing as an [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) "still going on". It will only be applied once for each event.

You can [remove the event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) or create an `if` statement on your event handler to check it the event default behavior should be prevented or not.